# Firefox alternative compatible with NoScript?

Tags: web-browser, security

I have been a huge fan of Firefox for years, and have grown an even bigger fan of its extension NoScript, which eases my mind a lot when browsing the web.

However, Mozilla announced that they were deprecating XUL extension in favor of WebExtension, which are way less powerful because a lot less integrated inside the program.

Looking at everything NoScript does, I'm about sure it will die the instant Firefox 57 come out, and want to step ahead of the curve.

I thought of Palemoon, but unless I didn't saw a hiden setting somewhere, NoScript isn't supported on it. Other Firefox forks I tried are either tightly coupled with the "main" Firefox, or not compatible with NoScript for other reasons.

What is a good alternative to Firefox that is compatible with NoScript? Or have a similar functionality/plugin/extension?

Primary goals:

- Free
- Compatible with NoScript, or have similar capabilities
- Support Linux (Debian) and Windows

Secondary goals:

- Open Source
- Firefox based
- Support uBlock origin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After emailing the NoScript maintainers, they validated that NoScript will work with WebExtensions, and that there is no need to worry.

Comment: To be honest, I’m surprised that you assumed it wouldn’t work (especially as it’s the top 5 most popular add-on). -- NoScript’s author blogged in 2015: [*WebExtensions API & NoScript*](https://hackademix.net/2015/08/22/webextensions-api-noscript/). In Mozilla’s blog post [*WebExtensions in Firefox 48*](https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2016/04/29/webextensions-in-firefox-48/) from 2016, they claim that NoScript’s XSS filter "perform much better as a WebExtension, with huge speed gains (20 times or more) in some cases over the existing XUL and XPCOM extension for many operations".